I want to give access to user to add or edit opportunity contact role but not edit opportunity standard fields.How to achieve this?
User has edit access on case.

From case record if user navigates to opp through the opp lookup field in case he must not be able to edit opp standard fields but ...
add or edit the opp contact roles in opp record related list.

I have tried giving edit access to user on opp the problem is user able to

Add opp contact role
Edit opp standard fields.

If I remove the edit access on opp user is not able to do both 1 and 2.
I want to achieve option 1 and not the ability to perform option 2.Any workaround for this ?

Retain CRUD on Opportunity but remove Edit in FLS for Opportunity Fields for user's profile/permission set
